# Output of a BJT

Tags: bjt

I don't have any confusion about the output current of a BJT: it is the current along the collector terminal, fair enough.

But now the problem I'm facing is what exactly the output voltage means in a transistor. At which point(s) does it appear? Somebody says Vce is the output voltage, others are saying the voltage across Rc is the output etc.,  etc. But which one exactly is it?

Comment: A BJT doesn't have "an output"; what is an in- and what an output depends on what you consider that way, so I'd say, *yes*, you do have a confusion about that! You need to consider the *application*, i.e. the whole circuit and what you consider as being the input to describe what the output is.

Comment: Also: It might help if you look at some **circuits** that use a BJT. A common circuit is a BJT used as a switch to switch on/off a load like a lightbulb or a motor. In such circuits the **base** is the input and the **collector** is the output as it connects to the load. There are also circuits where the emitter is the input. But don't worry about that at this stage, go study some **circuits** (Google for "BJT circuit" or "NPN circuit") and try to figure out how they work and what the input and output are, of the circuit, not the transistor.

Answer (score 1):

The "disagreements" you talk about are simply the differences between the three most basic ways of using a transistor as an amplifier (there are also some others). These three kinds of amplifier are called common emitter, common collector and common base.

For the common emitter amplifier that is the most widespread (good enough in amplifying both current and voltage), the output is the voltage between emitter and collector:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fepvllm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the common collector amplifier that has its own niche (amplifiers current a lot, voltage not at all), the output is accross the resistor on the collector circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYhMb8m.png)</sup>

Finally for the common base amplifier that is less usual (amplifies voltage a lot but current not at all) the output is between the base and collector:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXFV20m.png)</sup>

Comment: I'd correct "the three ways" to "the three basic ways", as you can design more complicated amplifiers (like a long-tailed pair, for instance) that don't fit any of these types exactly.

Comment: I agree, corrected.